# Force Format/Analyser on obfuscated/anti-disassembly file

Tags: ghidra

I have a clear `.class` file, which is likely obfuscated. However, Ghidra is not detecting it as Java, and shows it as `Raw binary`, which prevents me from using the `Java Class Analyzer` on the file.

How can I force Ghidra to identify the file as `Java class file` or to show me the `Java Class Analyzer`?

[image: Ghidra]

Comment: Hmm, good question, I wonder if that might have anything to do with the format of .class file Ghidra is expecting